# How can I optionally link against static or dynamic boost library using CMake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a CMake project that I sometimes want to compile against the static boost libraries, but I want to also make it easy to just use the dynamic libraries from the cmake GUI.  In my top level CMakeLists.txt I have this:

```
option(USE_STATIC_BOOST "Build with static BOOST libraries instead of dynamic" NO)
```

Then in a different file, I have the following logic set up:

```
if(USE_STATIC_BOOST)
   unset(Boost_LIBRARIES)
   message(WARNING "Linking against boost static libraries")
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
   set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
   find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread program_options system)
else(USE_STATIC_BOOST)
   unset(Boost_LIBRARIES)
   message(WARNING "Linking against boost dynamic libraries")
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
   set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
   find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread program_options system)
endif(USE_STATIC_BOOST)
```

This seems to work fine if I start from scratch and use:

```
cmake ../.. -DUSE_STATIC_BOOST=YES
```

However, when I use

```
ccmake ../..
```

I cannot get it to use the static libraries no matter what I do.  CMake appears to load the dynamic option into cache on startup and changing USE_STATIC_BOOST doesn't switch it.  I even tried to unset(Boost_LIBRARIES) to explicitly clear it out.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Using x86_64 Linux and g++ to compile.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To force the [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) CMake module to search for the desired libraries again, you have to clear the cache variables `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS`, i.e.:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ${USE_STATIC_BOOST})
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
unset(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR CACHE)
unset(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS CACHE)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread program_options system)
if(USE_STATIC_BOOST)
   message(STATUS "Linking against boost static libraries")
else()
   message(STATUS "Linking against boost dynamic libraries")
endif()
```

Note that the argument `CACHE` is necessary to make the [unset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html) command clear the variables in the cache.

Also note that once the option variable `USE_STATIC_BOOST` has been cached, you need to explicitly set the variable from the command line or edit the value in the cache file to make CMake notice the change:

```
cmake ../.. -DUSE_STATIC_BOOST=NO
```

Comment: Perfect - that worked great, thanks!
Follow up question: Do you know why setting Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS to ON/OFF needs to happen in the same scope as find_package?  If I take find_package out of the if/else/endif block above it doesn't honor the Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS flag.

Comment: @KdawgUD It works for me even if the scope is not the same. Anyway most of the code duplication in the if-else statement can be avoided (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I may have been fighting the cache issue when I was seeing what I thought was a scope issue.  I took your suggestion to remove duplicated code.  Cheers!