# using boost as static library by cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I am trying to link statically to boost and OpenCV. I managed to link to static version of OpenCV, but I have problem linking to static version of Boost.

in my cmake I have:

```
if (MSVC)
    add_definitions (-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
else (MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif (MSVC)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{BOOST_DIR})
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR $ENV{BOOST_DIR}/lib64-msvc-11.0)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test
${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

but when I am compiling it, I am getting this error:

```
 Error  4   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'test': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in test.obj libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib(path_traits.obj)
```

How can  fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680168/how-can-i-optionally-link-against-static-or-dynamic-boost-library-using-cmake)?

Comment: And it looks it *must me* linked with -mt-sgd- version of the library  -- see the description of the letters [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html), section 6.3.