# How to move cmake project to subdirectories?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I cant divide cmake-QT project into dirs.

In root dir i have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory(RSA)
add_subdirectory(updater_app/states)
add_subdirectory(updater_app)
```

In `updater_app` dir i have th following code, and it works fine:

```
project(Updater)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Quick)

list(INSERT CMAKE_MODULE_PATH 0 "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}   ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
qt5_generate_moc(main.cpp main.moc)

set(HEADERS worker.h )

set(SRC_LIST main.cpp worker.cpp)

add_executable(Updater ${SRC_LIST} ${src_moc} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(Updater Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(Updater Qt5::Quick)
target_link_libraries(Updater ${RSALIB})
```

But the similar code in another dir `updater_app/states` (of couse proj name and files - differs) doesn't work,
it gives me a million mistakes, such as:

```
error:left of '.append' must have class/struct/union
type is 'int'
error: C2664: 'bool QObject::setProperty(const char *,const QVariant &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'const QVariant &'
Reason: cannot convert from 'const char [5]' to 'const QVariant'
Source or target has incomplete type
error
```

and etc. When all the files was in the same dir with one cMake file - everything woked fine.

Please,help me anybody - how to divide the project to subdirectories?

Comment: The `find_package()` modules normally do store in CMake's cache if they have already been executed (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680168)). So have you tried to switch `updater_app/states` and `updater_app` and run it from scratch (clean binary output directory)? Generally speaking I would move the common parts into your main `CMakeLists.txt`, so e.g. finding Qt5 is only there once. Regarding your error message, this seems to be a problem with differing header versions. Do you have more then one QT version installed? And which OS/CMake do you use? Looks like Windows/VS.

Comment: Thank you for you comment! You gave me right answer -after dividing to folders it was nesecssery to add few includes (qstringlost, qvariant) , and problem of link was desided by more smart split to folders, so only the one subproj depends from other.

Comment: You are welcome. I've turned my comment into an answer and added an example for a subdirectories split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_package.html) modules normally do store in CMake's cache if they have already been executed.

> Once one of the calls succeeds the result variable will be set and stored in the cache so that no call will search again.

So calling everything twice doesn't help and I would recommend moving the common parts like finding Qt5 into your main `CMakeLists.txt`.

Regarding your error message, this looks like conflicting function or class declarations. It's hinting to be a problem with differing header versions.

My recommendation for your project structure would look - even if it differs a little from Qt's [CMake Manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) - something like this:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(Updater CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Quick)

add_subdirectory(RSA)
add_subdirectory(updater_app)
add_subdirectory(updater_app/states)
```

**updater_app/CMakeLists.txt**

```
qt5_generate_moc(main.cpp main.moc)

set(HEADERS worker.h )
set(SRC_LIST main.cpp main.moc worker.cpp)

add_executable(Updater ${SRC_LIST} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(Updater Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Quick RSALIB)
```

**Background Information**

- I've set `Qt5_DIR` via CMake's GUI or via command line option `cmake -DQt5_DIR:PATH=...` (in a standard Qt5.5.1 on MS Windows installation environment e.g. `C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/msvc2013/lib/cmake/Qt5`)
- You don't need the Qt5 specific `include_directories()`, `add_definitions()` or `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...` calls

  - They are set in the Qt5 CMake package by setting/appending [`INTERFACE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html), [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html), [`INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) and [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html)
  - Those `INTERFACE_...` target properties propagate their settings to all targets including it into its list of dependencies via [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_link_libraries.html)